# Which Nuget is to be used to create AAD aaplication?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create an AAD application using C#.

I have two options, either I can use:

1. Assembly:

   ```
   Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
   ```
2. Assembly:

   ```
   Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC
   ```

I would like to know the pros and cons of selecting option 1 or option 2 ?

Can someone please provide me an insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RABC is much latest, but I will still suggest Microsoft.Azrue.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient as it contains more parameters while creating application. Thus you will have more customization option available.

```
        public IList<ExtensionProperty> ExtensionProperties { get; set; }
        public string SamlMetadataUrl { get; set; }
        public IList<RequiredResourceAccess> RequiredResourceAccess { get; set; }
        public IList<string> ReplyUrls { get; set; }
        public string RecordConsentConditions { get; set; }
        public bool? PublicClient { get; set; }
        public IList<PasswordCredential> PasswordCredentials { get; set; }
        public bool Oauth2RequirePostResponse { get; set; }
        public IList<OAuth2Permission> Oauth2Permissions { get; set; }
        public bool Oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching { get; set; }
        public bool Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow { get; set; }
        public string LogoutUrl { get; set; }
        public IList<Guid> KnownClientApplications { get; set; }
        public IList<KeyCredential> KeyCredentials { get; set; }
        public IList<string> IdentifierUris { get; set; }
        public string Homepage { get; set; }
        public string GroupMembershipClaims { get; set; }
        public string ErrorUrl { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public bool? AvailableToOtherTenants { get; set; }
        public IList<AppRole> AppRoles { get; set; }
        public string AppId { get; set; }
        public IList<AddIn> AddIns { get; set; }
        public IList<DirectoryObject> Policies { get; set; }
        public IList<ServiceEndpoint> ServiceEndpoints { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them can be used for you. But the version of [Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RABC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC/3.4.0-preview) is much latest, and the latest version of [Microsoft.Azrue.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) is 2016.

Besides, Microsoft strongly recommends you to use Microsoft Graph instead of [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) to access Azure Active Directory resources, so suggest you use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph).

For the details about Microsof Graph or Azure AD Graph, you could read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

Comment: The only issue is [Microsoft.Azrue.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC/3.4.0-preview) supports RequiredResourceAccess parameter as part of application creation. But I can't find any way to pass RequiredResourceAccess as parameter while creating application via [Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RABC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC/3.4.0-preview).